# Singleton in swift to Objective-C giving error property not found of type XYZ *

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a function in swift as follows

```
public class XYZ:NSObject {

public static func getInstance() -> GlobalEventBus {
    return globalEventBusInstance
}

public static var xyzInstance:XYZ = XYZ()
var initialized:Bool?
public func dispatchEvent(customEvent:CustomEvent) { }
override init() {
    initialized = true
} 
}
```

I used the getInstance function in objective C implementation as follows

```
@implementation SomeFile


- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

 /* log a message */
 - (void)sendEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
 {

id message = [command argumentAtIndex:0];


XYZ *xyzInstance = [XYZ getInstance];
CustomEvent *customEvent = [CustomEvent alloc];

xyzInstance.dispatchEvent(customEvent)
//customEvent.eventType =

}

@end
```

The problem i am seeing is that I see an error 
"Property dispatchEvent not found on object of type XYZ *"

Does it have anything to do with the fact that the instance variable being returned is a static variable? What am I doing wrong? Please help

Thank you

Nikhil

Comment: Did you import the system generated header, `#import "Modulename-Swift.h"`?

Comment: @Rob I imported it. I am able to see other classes shown correctly. But I think it's only the singletons that are causing problems. I am able to see all the properties in the customEvent class. With singletons only I am not able to see the non static properties

Comment: Unrelated, you can simplify your singleton implementation to a single line: `public static let sharedInstance = XYZ()` and lose `getInstance` method. It's redundant and unnecessary. Also, your creation of `[CustomEvent alloc]` should be `[[CustomEvent alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Objective-C code, you have a line that says:

```
xyzInstance.dispatchEvent(customEvent)
```

That's Swift. You want:

```
[xyzInstance dispatchEvent:customEvent];
```

Comment: I feel sheepish. :) That's what I was looking for Rob. Thank you.